# Maven project created from Old (1.x) Archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-archetype

I'm trying to learn Maven following this [Getting Started Guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html).

I've Apache Maven 3.0.1 on Linux. I've issued the following command to create a first project:

```
yes | mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart \
  -DgroupId=org.obliquid.helpers \
  -DartifactId=obliquid-helpers \
  -Dversion=0.1
```

However, in the output I read:

```
[INFO] project created from Old (1.x) Archetype in dir: ...
```

How can I use a current version for the Archetype? Is the guide that I'm reading outdated?

As a sub-question, I've noticed that in the pom.xml mentions junit version 3.8.1, while I'd like to use junit version 4.8.x - How to change that? I can just change the version number in the XML?

Is there a better guide or book that you can suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version you are using as well as the guide you are referring is current enough.  You can ignore the message.  The project that is created does work fine with the latest maven.

As for junit, you can change the version of the dependency appropriately. The project that is created using archetype:generate is only an indicative one, which is meant to be customized.

In addition to what you are looking at, you could also look [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/)

Comment: So what is the message "Old (1.x) Archetype" for?

Comment: As of 2017-04-12, the [Guide to Creating Archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) asks for contributions to update it to the last version.

Comment: You can read last version there (currently 1.4): https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/

Answer (score 3):

If you include **-DinteractiveMode=true** in your mvn archetype:generate command:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DgroupId=org.obliquid.helpers \
    -DartifactId=obliquid-helpers \
    -Dversion=0.1 \
    -DinteractiveMode=true
```

you are presented with a (large) catalog of available mvn archetypes, along with a brief description of each.

Currently, a couple of the best simple Java app archetypes in that list are:

```
1844: remote -> org.spilth:java9-minimalist-quickstart
```

and

```
1966: remote -> pl.org.miki:java8-quickstart-archetype
```

The second one includes a test scope that uses JUnit version 4.11 for unit-tests.  To use that archetype you just need to specify the archetypeGroupId and archetypeArtifactId as in:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=pl.org.miki \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=java8-quickstart-archetype \
    -DgroupId=org.obliquid.helpers \
    -DartifactId=obliquid-helpers \
    -Dversion=0.1
```

For some reason mvn archetype:generate assumes **archetypeVersion=1.0** even when the archetype metadata indicates a different version for the latest/release.

To specify an archetype version besides 1.0 you just need to define a value for the **archetypeVersion** property, e.g.

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 \
    -DgroupId=org.obliquid.helpers \
    -DartifactId=obliquid-helpers \
    -Dversion=0.1 \
    -DinteractiveMode=true
```

Find out what versions are available by visiting https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/ with a web browser.

Comment: Link is dead, but you can read last version there (currently 1.4): https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/